# Meaning of "where every mask cracks, that is the hardest illusion of all"

Tags: phrase-meaning

[Source](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/editorial-on-novak-djokovic-victory-in-french-open-2016-the-djokovic-standard/article8697386.ece)

> His mental resilience, moreover, has both drawn from and supplemented the physical to a point where he now appears invulnerable. In professional sport, **where every mask cracks, that is the hardest illusion of all**.

What is meant by the bold part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **mask** is used to hide who you really are. When it cracks/falls, it reveals the person behind it. 
In the same lexical field, an **illusion** gives a fake look of reality to something that isn't real.

The article states that, in professional sport, every mask cracks, which means it is especially hard to fake/hide things and be someone you're not.

Thus, the author writes that Djokovic appearing invulnerable, in a field where it is very difficult to act like something you're not, is the **hardest illusion of all**.

Comment: MadWard I didn't get the illusion part. What is illusion here? And why is that illusion hard?

Comment: Second meaning in the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/illusion): **something that is not really what it seems to be**. The illusion here is that Djoko appears invulnerable, while he obviously isn't (he is a human being). It is hard because of the previous sentence, because it's complicated to appear like something you're not in professional sports.